# Change the color when select by clicking using Javascript CSS

Tags: html, css, angularjs

I have a calendar with date and time slots. After selecting date, time slots will come. From there you can select the time by clicking. Now, I want to change the color of selected item in time slot. Suppose, if you click on 11AM-12PM time slot then it should get red color and then you click on next time, i.e. `12PM-1PM`, so `12PM-1Pm` will get red color and son on. I have tried by using focus, it is not working. As I am already using hover. May be for that reason `focus` and `hover` not working at same time. May be I need to use something `onclick`. I have added my plunker code below. This is CSS :

```css
.frame {
    width: 100%;
    height: 400px;

    margin-left: 0%;
    border: 1px solid #777777;
    overflow: auto;
}

.datepicker {
    width: 100%;
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
}

.datepicker li {
    cursor: pointer;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ededed;
    padding: 10px;
}
.datepicker li:hover {
    background: #EEE;
}
.text-center {
    text-align: center;
}

.border {
    border: 1px solid red;
}
```

[Plunker link](http://plnkr.co/edit/DmIOgISVcXnLp3DvQoFP?p=preview)

Comment: you must use javascript for event handling like click

Comment: Can you add a key called **isSelected** and set it on click. Also add a condition on class to like `class:{className: $data.isSelected}`. Also make sure to reset isSelected of all timeSlots and then set current one as true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can target selected item via [`$index`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat) and then add a class to it using [`ng-class`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClass) directive. Basically, you need to:

1. Add selected time index variable to your scope:

   ```
   $scope.selectedTimeIndex = -1;
   ```
2. Pass `$index` to `selectTime` and conditionally add `selected` class:

   ```
   <li ng-click="selectTime(time, $index)" ng-class="{selected: $index == selectedTimeIndex}" ng-repeat="time in timeValues">{{time}}</li>
   ```
3. Change `selectedTimeIndex` on `selectTime` call:

   ```
   $scope.selectTime = function(time, index) {
       $scope.selectedTimeIndex = index;
       // The rest of your function.
   };
   ```
4. Add `selected` class to your .css:

   ```
   .selected {
       background: red;
   }
   ```

Simple example [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/3wLZoXhTA32sFtHkW6SJ?p=preview).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, as @Chris said, you need to use Javascript because you want to show that upon click.

I am not familiar with AngularJs, but conceptually u can add the class

```
.selected {
   background-color: red;
}
```

And then add this class to the selected item and remove that from the lastSelected item.